Probability two independent random walks on graph meet

It's exercise from J. Norris book on Markov chains.
I'm thinking on involving time-reversabiility but can't figure out the proper way. What I mean, if X meet Y at some point S, then we can just replace a path of Y (B $\rightarrow$ S) by that of X (S $\rightarrow$ B), but then I'm stucking. Any hints?

Here’s a hint: the given graph is bipartite.

@Pranay and that gives zero probability in (a), thanks.

It also says something about (b). Not a complete answer but an equivalent formulation that might be easier to analyse.

@Pranay You mean to consider separately odd and even moments of time and get two Markov chains? Let h(x, y) be probability of two walks meet starting from x and y. Then we can write down two linear systems for h(x, y) considering one step of each chain. They are not so large as if we do one step in original chain. Or you mean another way of solving problem?

I mean the following. If the two particles start from $A$ and $E$ and meet at a vertex after $n$ steps, this gives a walk from $A$ to $E$ with $2n$ steps. Conversely, given any walk from $A$ to $E$, it must have even length because the graph is bipartite, so we can break it into two halves, where the vertex at the halfway point is the meeting point. This means you just have to compute the probability that a particle starting from $A$ reaches $E$ in an even number of steps.

Actually, my previous comment is incorrect. The probability of meeting is not the same as probability of going from $A$ to $E$ because the time-reversal of walk doesn’t have the same probability as the original walk.
